# Given a square grid of side length N and m objects, design a bijection between each object and a unique set of coordinates

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory, proof-writing, computer-science, hash-function

Given a square grid of side length N and m objects, can I design a 1-1 relationship between each object and a unique set of coordinates in that 2-D plane?

Imagine the context being something like storing objects in a hashmap of id to object and needing to calculate the L1 norm / Manhattan distance between any two objects quickly.

My initial thought was to use the mod operator and floor division, e.g. if we have $10$ objects and a $5$ by $5$ grid, maybe the unique location of object 7 will be $(25 \% 7, 25 // 7)$ = $(4, 3)$?

I'm less interested in an answer than I am in the thinking / creative process used to come up with a solution, and how to prove the answer is correct or disprove such a function exists.

Thank you!

Comment: It should be `7%5, 7//5` or `x%n, x//n` in general for side length $n$.

Comment: It is definitely possible. There exists a one-to-one mapping between $\mathbb{N}^2$ and $\mathbb{N}$ so there are definitely plenty of mappings between arbitrary grids and a subset of the natural numbers. $$(m,n)\mapsto \dfrac{(m+n)(m+n+1)}{2}+m$$

Comment: how did you design this particular function?

Comment: @Matt it is the Cantor Pairing Function. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function. It turns out it is the unique quadratic bijection between $\mathbb{N}^2$ and $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Edit: probably unique. I thought the theorem was proven. Apparently it is still open.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your idea is that the values may fall outside the square.  Object $1$ will be at $(0,10)$ and object $9$ will be at $(7,2)$, both outside your $5 \times 5$ square.  The simplest approach is to use the side of the square as the denominator, so object $n$ goes at $(n\%N,n//N)$.  This just puts them in the first columns as far as you need to go.